# Spark Tasks not evenly distributed among executors (google cloud dataproc)

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I noticed that after a repartition the tasks do not always get evenly distributed among the executors. This causes an enormous buildup. The repartition function randomly assigns a partition number for each item. It seems that the tasks are quite evenly distributed, so I do not think the repartition is the cause of the issue. Is there a way to solve this issue?

[image: spark event timeline]

Comment: Are you able to share any details of your job/code? Especially the ordering of the different transformations, number of partitions in your repartition, and size of the data if possible.

Comment: The job simply writes messages from kafka (max 1MB) to bigtable. The kafka queue has 9 partitions and it gets repartitioned to 70 partitions atm. The messages may vary in size and are therefore randomly shuffled (random partition number for each message).

Comment: The timeline seems a bit short, in which case things like YARN dynamic allocation might not be kicking in properly; what happens if you try running with `spark.executor.instances=999` (which should grab as many slots as available up to 999 and effectively flips `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` to false)?

Comment: We don't use dynamic allocation: we work with a fixed amount of executors.

Comment: Probably the real issue is how to go from x (here 9) unbalanced kafka partitions to y partitions that are equally divided over the executors (in a way that the content is shuffled)?